# Which journals publish PhD abstracts?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, journals

With the flavour of this question:  [Which journals publish expository work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work),  I would like to ask the following question

> Which journals publish Ph.D. thesis abstracts?

Please post one resource per answer so that it is easy for people to sort the list by voting up/down.

Answer (score 7):

The journal [Dissertationes Mathematicae](http://journals.impan.gov.pl/dm/) publishes quite a lot of entire Ph.D. *theses*, and the abstracts (which may be fairly long and quite often also include the table of contents of the thesis) are free to view.

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, the [Australian Mathematics Society Bulletin](http://www.austms.org.au/Bulletin) publishes "Abstracts of Ph.D. Theses":

> The BULLETIN of the Australian
>   Mathematical Society publishes
>   Abstracts of Australasian Ph.D.
>   Theses. The abstract submitted to the
>   BULLETIN may be the abstract included
>   in the thesis itself. However, the
>   BULLETIN will accept abstracts of up
>   to three pages, which may include
>   references. All the mathematical
>   sciences are covered, including pure
>   and applied mathematics, probability
>   and mathematical statistics,
>   mathematical physics, and mathematical
>   computer science.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some announcements of results of PhD theses in the [comptes rendus mathematique](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/comptes-rendus-mathematique/)