# Which journals publish applied mathematics with mostly pure mathematics content?

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, journals, applications

In the spirit of [Which journals publish expository work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work) please advise:

> What consistently high quality journals (1) today publish results that would otherwise go to a pure mathematics journal were it not for (2) the included applied content, the motivation, and/or the examples?

*PNAS* (if the paper is not long), *Lecture Notes in Mathematics* (if it is long), *Journal of Interdisciplinary Mathematics*, *SIAM* subject journals, *Journal of Modern Dynamics, *Journal of Mathematical Biology*, *Bulletin of Mathematical Biology*, and *International Journal of General Systems* go without saying.

(But are the last three read by working mathematicians these days?)

**What about others?**

To make the question answerable:

> Ideally suggest a journal per answer with comments. So that others can vote on it, and an answer can be accepted eventually.

**1** - Many applied journals are neither read nor refereed by mathematicians, primarily working in mathematics.

That makes it difficult to get appropriate referees to give advise on submitted papers, either at all or else in a timely manner. If only because of, for example, notation or terminology lag (APS journals for example).

Please only suggest journals that are not *too* obscure or seem like they going to be obscure in the future. Journals that, due to the founders or team are likely "up and comers" are OK. (Nothing wrong with obscurity, but as you probably know . . . arXiv by itself is often more widely read in comparison . . . )

**2** - Content that is inappropriate in a pure mathematics journal, for it contains sufficiently detailed applications. *Yet the applications by themselves cannot be coherently published separately from the majority of the paper, which begins with and discusses a problem of primarily mathematical interest and with conventional mathematical rigour.*

*Updated*. After a couple years maybe some new journals were founded that are not well known yet but may be good quality, especially with application to computer science. If so, those would be good answers.

Comment: I've never been able to really decide an answer to this question myself, after a lot of time. Splitting off the applied part into a second paper is the usual decision. But this results in it getting published later. For it would usually then go through revision and resubmission, unlike the first part. For whether the applications are clear or interesting separately is very difficult to judge as the author who wrote it as one single discussion.

Comment: http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?area=2600&category=2604&country=all&year=2014&order=sjr&min=0&min_type=cd

Comment: I don't think I would necessarily assume that the "applied content" automatically makes the paper unsuitable for a pure math journal.  If the mathematical results are of interest by themselves, then explaining how they are used in an applied context could only increase the interest, I would think.

Comment: Math Proc Camb Phil Soc: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=PSP     (If it doesn't satisfy point 1 of your requirements then I don't think I want to know :)  )

Comment: @NateEldredge: I doubt that; I once received a review that explicitly asked me to delete all details about the applied stuff and numerical results, and to retain only the math (which the referee found publishable), with at best citations to applied contexts!

Comment: Math Proc Camb Phil Soc, great journal: criterion 1 *over*fulfilled :) However that's a top *pure* mathematics publication. I agree with N.E. the interest would increase in my opinion. But that's a minority opinion, isn't it? In practice if a paper contains say near the end a few pages of physical application discussion, for example w/ SEM figures (void distribution for example), if it's not a special issue, it usually strikes an editor as off topic. Or some referees refuse to review it, arguing they feel they can't comment on whole paper due to the application assertions. And months go by...

Comment: @Suvrit: Well, I stand corrected.  Obviously I wasn't that referee :-)

Comment: @Suvrit That's my experience too. Revise: delete the application ``assertions,'' retain the mathematics, to publish. Then work hard to make the applications readable without reproducing the mathematical result in the now separate applications paper. (It's already published or in press or considered inappropriate in turn in the physical journal!) Numerous citations to applications also are asked to be removed from the mathematical publication. Without the physical discussion (gone) one cannot provide evidence that the result can be applied in these ways, after all. A catch-22...

Comment: I had exactly the same question two years ago with this paper: http://www.aimsciences.org/journals/pdfs.jsp?paperID=10624&mode=full -- I've been extremely impressed with the relatively new Journal of Computational Dynamics. I experienced high quality of anonymous reviews, a relatively quick turnaround time, and a top-notch theory-savvy editorial board. That being said, I wish they'd go open access and lose the comic sans from their website.

Comment: V.N. please post the journal as an answer if you believe it is a good fit. I have not heard of it but will look into it.

Comment: Would the Journal of Fourier Analysis and Applications count? Many papers I've read there could have been turned into pure math papers without too much effort had they (or the general field) not been so applied.

Comment: Yes, I would say. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Came across my own question and saw that most discussion was in the comments. Here are some answers. Question also got relatively many views. So here are some answers.

1. Here is one recently that I would like to see succeed: *Compositionality*

https://compositionality-journal.org/

2. *Mathematical structures in computer science*

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science

3. *Mathematics of computation*

https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/all_issues.html