# Would a journal such as Bulletin of the AMS accept an article from a student?

Tags: journals, mathematical-writing

I am a masters student, and am currently writing an expository article on an area of applied maths for a class project. I plan to work on it for several more months. One of my major goals is to improve my expository writing skills, and I thought one way to achieve this might be to try and submit this article to a journal for peer review. The topic is also of significant interest in several fields.

I have checked and Bulletin of the AMS and Notices of the AMS have both published work similar in flavor to what I have in mind. However, all of the articles I have read from these journals so far were authored by senior professors. I'm not sure if this because articles from established experts are preferred, or if it's because more junior people may have an incentive to focus on their original research rather than expository writing. Would it be pointless to submit as a student? If so, are there other venues that could be reasonable?

Comment: The question is maybe more suitable for https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: However, it may be more savvy to send your work to less prestigious journal. You increase the chances to get it published, which I guess is more important for you at the moment that publishing on a top journal.

Comment: No: I think you are correct that expository articles in the *Bulletin* are only from established experts.  See https://mathoverflow.net/q/15366/454 for journals that accept expository articles in mathematics.

Comment: In principle, the Bulletin of the AMS should be willing to consider any expository essay. However, in practice the articles are usually written by current experts on the most recent advances in a particular area. If you submit it and the editors decide your article is not suitable, then you should get a quick response from them (without having the paper refereed). Otherwise, they'll send it out to be refereed.

Comment: @MaurizioMoreschi, perhaps in this case I would agree that *Bull. AMS* is probably not right for what this student has in mind... However in general I strongly disagree that it is more important to get published quickly, than get published in a top journal. One article in a top journal is often the difference between getting a job and not getting a job -- and so I would say one should always aim as high as possible...

Comment: @NickGill I was indeed considering this specific situation (given that this would be the student's first work and that he/she sounds pretty interested in the feedback), certainly not trying to give a general rule! I am actually in a similar situation. I will submit (probably in the spring) my first research paper. Although I think my work is good, I will probably not choose a top journal, because having a confirmation that I can write a paper acceptable for a journal is more important for me at this stage. Again, of course, this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 10):

There is another venue for this sort of work: The [Graduate Journal of Mathematics](http://www.gradmath.org/). It publishes papers by graduate students or papers that would be of interest to graduate students. So, expository papers can be a good fit, especially if they contain something new and interesting (e.g. a list of open problems, a worked example, a new way to prove an old result, etc).

The normal thing for you to do, as an author, would be to check out the journal website and see if there is an editor on the editorial board who looks like they know a bit about the field. That editor would probably know potential referees. If you can't find an editor in applied math, you could send it to me (I am an editor), and I could probably find a referee (with a bit more effort).

You could also post your preprint on arxiv.

Answer (score 7):

Any good journal is supposed to evaluate papers according their quality, not the author's affiliation. The cases when papers of students were accepted in top journals are known. But Bull AMS is a bad example: it does not publish research papers; it publishes surveys.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if this is the case, then why isn't the process double blind, where the author's affiliation is not known to reviewers?