# Does anyone know a journal like Expositiones Mathematicae, except not by Elsevier?

Tags: journals

Meaning primarily expository articles aimed at a wide-ranging mathematical audience, at the same technical level. But not by such a predatory publisher.

Comment: I recomond u [this journal](http://www.anubih.ba/Journals/SJMATH.html) called Sarajevo

Comment: "The journal does not consider papers of expository nature "

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work

Comment: for the sake of fairness and precision, the term [predatory publisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_publishing) has the specific meaning of a publisher that _"charges publication fees to authors without checking articles for quality and legitimacy and without providing the other editorial and publishing services that legitimate academic journals provide"._ This does not apply to Expositiones Mathematicae, does it?

Comment: The MO question [Which journals publish expository work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work) is probably the most useful resource on the web for mathematicians seeking an answer to that question. Can I suggest that people add their answers to that question rather than here? Then all the information is kept in one place.

Comment: Carlo, many people use "predatory" for Elsevier, with some justification: they prey on academia and would die without us. The Wikipedia definition is arguably too narrow. (Plus, see the section "Bohannon's experiment" of the Wikipedia page, which shows Elsevier behaving exactly according to that defn of predatory publisher.) I think for Elsevier, **parasitic** is even more apt: they suck out as much of universities' blood as they can while still leaving us alive.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I agree with Tom Leinster; that Wikipedia finds this page suitable doesn't mean that there consensus on this meaning, which indeed in this case is somewhat restrictive (and we can't be sure that these publishers, do not influence in some way the Wikipedia information to appear on the "good" side).

Answer (score 4):

You can try l'[Enseignement Mathématique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Enseignement_math%C3%A9matique), published by the [European Mathematical Society](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/journal.php?jrn=lem).

Comment: Pete Clark's experience with EM may be worth bearing in mind: see point 2 in his question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work

Comment: ...and Felipe Voloch's answer to Pete Clark's question: https://mathoverflow.net/a/15404

Answer (score 4):

Some journals publishing only surveys: Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Sugaku Expositions, Russian Mathematical Surveys. Some journals also publish surveys besides research articles.